# Middlewares aninhados

Tags: php, laravel, middleware

Eu gostaria de permitir acesso à algumas páginas apenas se usuário estiver logado.

Eu fiz assim:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'usuario'], function (){
    /* Minhas páginas */
});
```

Até aí tudo bem, mas eu gostaria de verificar se a senha já é a atual (se `sn_senha_atual == 'S'` )

Eu pensei em usar middlewares aninhadas, porém ele dá um erro **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** ao tentar usar assim:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'usuario'], function (){
    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'senha'], function (){
      /*  minhas paginas */
    });
});
```

Meu middleware **usuário** está assim:

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if( !Auth::check() ){
            return redirect()->back();
        }
            return $next($request);
    }
```

E meu middleware **senha** está assim:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        if( $user->sn_senha_atual == 'N' ){
           // echo "Alterar id: ".$user->id;
            return redirect()->route( 'usu.alterar');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
```

Como faço para que depois de verificar se usuário está logado, verificar se a senha é a atual?

**[EDIT 1]**

Coloque a pagina de alterar fora do middlware de senha, mas agora parece que middleware usuario nao deixa passar

```
    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'usuario'], function (){
            Route::group( ['middleware' => 'senha'], function (){
              Route::group(['as' => 'usu.', 'prefix' => 'usuario'], function (){
               Route::get('',['as' => 'index','middleware' => 'senha', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@index']);
               Route::get('cadastrar',['as' => 'create', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@create']);
               Route::post('salvar',['as' => 'store', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@store']);
               Route::post('delete',['as' => 'remove', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@remove']);
               Route::post('edit',['as' => 'edit', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@edit']);
               Route::post('update',['as' => 'update', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@update']);
               Route::get('sair',['as' => 'sair','middleware' => 'senha', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@sair']);
               Route::get('logoff',['as' => 'logoff', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@logOff']);
                 });
            });
           Route::post('alterar',['as' => 'alterar', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@alterarSenha']);
        });
```

Comment: E por acaso as páginas para qual está redirecionando não estão dentro do grupo que possui o *middleware*?

Comment: Não estão, estão dentro de grupo simples, por exemplo : `Route::group(['as' => 'item.', 'prefix' => 'item'], function (){`

Comment: Esta sintaxe de múltiplos *middlewares* é condizente com a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-middleware)?

Comment: `Route::middleware(['first', 'second'])->group(function () {` Desse jeito está dizendo que $Required parameter $callback missing

Comment: Assim também deu o mesmo erro: `Route::group( ['middleware' => ['usuario', 'senha']]`

Comment: Seguinte você deve ta fazendo assim, o middlweare de verificação de senha deve está contido na rota `us.alterar`, por isso ele confere de novo e manda você ir para a mesma pagina, é isso que não pode fazer, o que tem que fazer é tirar a rota `us.alterar` o `middleware` senha ... entendeu?

Comment: realmente tirei dentro e não deu mais a mensagem, porém, ele não entra mais na página de alterar.

Comment: porque deveria ser get e não post muda isso!

Comment: É. Deu certo. Era isso mesmo.. Coloquei para fora de todos os grupos e funcionou. Por favor, adicione como resposta

Comment: @adventistaam pode adicionar você mesmo e colocar um texto explicando o que aconteceu... !!! é legal também responder! vai lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com as ajudas dos colegas e com o comentário chave do amigo [Virgilio Novic](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/54880/virgilio-novic)

A rota onde estava a página para alterar a senha estava dentro do middleware senha também, então acho que era que isso que estava dando os demais redirecionamentos ( **ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS** )

Assim era assim:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'usuario'], function (){
    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'senha'], function (){
       Route::group(['as' => 'usu.', 'prefix' => 'usuario'], function (){
            Route::get('alterar',['as' => 'alterar', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@alterarSenha']);
         });
    });
});
```

Depois ficou assim:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => 'usuario'], function (){
    Route::group( ['middleware' => 'senha'], function (){
       Route::group(['as' => 'usu.', 'prefix' => 'usuario'], function (){

         });
    });
});

 Route::get('alterar',['as' => 'alterar', 'uses' => 'UsuarioController@alterarSenha']);
```

Também, de acordo com a [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#route-group-middleware) o grupo de `middleware` pode ficar assim:

```
Route::middleware(['first', 'second'])->group(function () {
```

ou assim:

```
Route::group( ['middleware' => ['usuario','senha']], function (){
```

Obrigado pela ajuda, amigos